# JQuery gives "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" when run

Tags: jquery

I am using a JQuery plugin which is an input mask for a text box. The textbox and JQuery is part of a custom user control and is added dynamically to a repeater control, which is part of a wizard step and control.

However, when I reach the step where the repeater and the user control with JQuery is added, the JQuery throws the following error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

All my code is this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


jQuery(function($){
   $('#<%= date.ClientID %>').mask("99/99/9999");

});
</script>

<asp:textbox id="date" runat="server"/>
```

So, I am really stuck as to why I am getting this problem. Can anyone help me, because I do no know why I should be getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's that invalid `<script>` tag, this:

```
<script src="src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since that tag's malformed, the plugin isn't being executed, so `.mask()` isn't a method jQuery objects have in your page...once you fix the `<script>` include it'll fix the issue.

Comment: That's me doing copying and pasting - that error doesn't exist in the actual mark up

Comment: @Andy5 - ...if you don't paste the *actual* markup, no one can help, you're introducing *other* errors.

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASP.NET like it seems, I suspect the problem is your have your controls placed in a naming container.  This adds a prefix to all controls and will change how you need to target the controls using jQuery.

Take a look in Developer Tools in IE or FireBug in Firefox and see if the IDs are what you think they are.

Example: A control named CommentsGridView might become: `tcBanner_tbComments_commentsTabContent_CommentsGridView`

This is taken from one of my projects.

Let me know if I'm anywhere close or if you need more detail.

Comment: This isn't the issue :) It's the plugin not being defined for whatever reason...in this case an invalid `<script>` tag :)

Comment: Ah, well his original post was light on code so I took a shot :) I guess object not defined doesn't make sense for my guess though. Would be a null error.

Comment: See my earlier comment - I copied the markup from my source and was pasted in correctly into the question box. Therefore, Nick's comment is not the solution to my problem. I think your point about the Id's is certainly worth exploring. If ASPX muddle's the Ids what is the approach I need to fix this?

Comment: Any naming container should have a method called "FindControl". But, depending on what you're trying to do, you might just need to figure out what the prefix is and hardwire it in. *ducks tomatoes being thrown by purists*

Comment: The custom user control is added dynamically and depends upons what the user does in the previous step. Therefore, this user control for dates could be added any number of times and could be the first or nth number in the list of controls inside the repeater. I thought using the textbox id with either Client ID or Unique ID will always ensure that the the JQuery plugin will find the control. I am not clear in your approach of using FindControl on something that will be client side. Please explain